# Making targets out of computed variables in make

Tags: makefile

Here is an example that doesn't work

```
say-hello := greeting
say-bye := farewell

greeting:
    @echo "Hello"

farewell:
    @echo "Bye"

.SECONDEXPANSION:
%-guvnah: $$(say-$*)
    @echo "Target was: $(say-$*)"
```

The command

```
make hello-guvnah
```

Should yield

```
hello
Target was: greeting
```

But shows only

```
Target was: greeting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it will if you double escape the `$*` in the prerequisite so it gets expanded during secondary expansion instead of the first pass:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
%-guvnah: $$(say-$$*)
    @echo "Target was: $(say-$*)"
```

Comment: I did it with `%-guvnah: $$(say-%)` eventuallu but that works just as well. Thanks